# PHP PHPSESSID exploit confusion

Tags: php, html, session

I am confused about the PHPSESSID exploit. If I change `document.cookie` to another active user's (on a simple social media site like youtube or instagram [just an example]) `PHPSESSID`, will the page reload with me being logged into that user's account? Will I also need to know that user's password? Note: I will not actually do that but I want to learn what would happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on the target site's security checks.

If the site assumes that the `PHPSESSID` cookie is enough to authorize access, then yes stealing someone's session would be sufficient to impersonate her, without the need to know her password.

Sites often have additional measures though: they might check whether other parameters such as the IP address or the User Agent have changed during the session and if they detect such a change, invalidate the session and deny access.

Sessions typically also have an expiration, so that if you obtain a session cookie, say from a browser that has been left unattended for hours, the site may deny access because it is past expiration. You see this often with banking sites that will show you a popup telling you that your session expired or is about to expire.

Finally, if a user logs out, a good site will destroy the session. Even though you have the `PHPSESSID` cookie, when you present it to the server it won't find the matching session because it would have been destroyed.

Comment: Thank you. Let's say a site has bad security and all you need is the `PHPSESSID`. When I go to Inspect Element and change to `document.cookie = "PHPSESSID=somesessionid"`, will the page refresh and will I be logged in as her?

Comment: Changing session id is the easy part, obtaining it in the first place is the hard one.

Comment: @Naktibalda , if I somehow find someone's session id and change it using `document.cookie = "PHPSESSID=theusersessid`, will the page refresh and will I be logged in as her (assuming the site's security is bad and all I need is the `PHPSESSID`)?

Comment: @RichterB., assuming PHPSESSID is the only piece of data used by the web application to determine if a user is authenticated or not, then YES.